# Write URL data to file is empty

Tags: java, string, file, file-io, bufferedwriter

I am trying to get data from URL and write it to a file, and I got the data from the URL but the file is empty, and below my code:

```
public class LiveRead {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            URL u = new URL("http://quotes.rest/qod.json?category=life");
            HttpURLConnection hr = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            if (hr.getResponseCode() == 200){
                InputStream im = hr.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(im));
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("/Users/macos/Desktop/json");
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fo));
                String line = br.readLine();
                while (line != null){
                    System.out.println(line);
                    bw.write(line);
                    bw.newLine();
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and when I open `/Users/macos/Desktop/json`, that file is empty. What's wrong and how to resolve it?

Comment: try flushing and closing the outputstream, also debug your code to ensure that data is actually being read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explicitly `flush` and `close` your writer, and not assume Java will do it for you when the program terminates:

```
bw.flush();
bw.close();
```